# How to convert string to list in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

My question is how to convert a string to a list in Python. When a user enters a string I need to convert it to a list.

```
user enters => ip1: 1.2 
               ip2: 3.2

After entering it will becomes "['1.2', '3.2']"

 Here is how to convert the above string value to List for looping the values further.
 
   how to get Output => ['1.2','3.2']
```

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you already have the input in a single multiline text. You can use list comprehension with `split`:

```py
user_input = "ip1: 1.2\nip2: 3.2"
output = [line.split(": ")[1] for line in user_input.splitlines()]
print(output) # ['1.2', '3.2']
```

Answer (score 0):

You're gonna want to use the string library's default `.replace` and `.split` methods. This can take some tinkering, but you can accomplish this more easily if you know that it will be similarly formatted every time.

For example:

```
sample_str = "['1.2', '3.2']"
decomposed_str = sample_str.replace("[", "")
decomposed_str = decomposed_str.replace("]", "")
decomposed_str = decomposed_str.replace("'", "")
list = decomposed_str.split(", ")
```

This will give you the output of `['1.2','3.2']`

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a simple solution

```
user_input = "['1.2', '3.2']"
new_list = eval(user_input)
```

eval() can change the output type as list